# How to stop Getting 405 error Method not allowed?

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, django-views

I am trying to make my django project to work but somehow I always come to get this error

> Method Not Allowed (POST): /

I have tried using decorators like @csrf_exempt like in the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/csrf/) as to not encounter csrf errors and yet I came to this error.Please tell me what's the problem with my code...

**urls.py**

```
from test.views import HomePageView,predict    
urlpatterns = [ 
path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name="homepage"),
path('predict', predict, name="predict"),]
```

**views.py**

```python
class HomePageView(Notif, TemplateView):
    template_name = "homepage.html"

    def predict(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     if request == 'POST':
        text = self.request.get_json().get('message')
        # check if text is valid
        response = get_response(text)
        message = {'answer': response}
        return JsonResponse(message)

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(HomePageView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

**app.js**

```js
onSendButton(chatbox) {
        var textField = chatbox.querySelector('input');
        let text1 = textField.value
        if (text1 === "") {
            return;
        }

        let msg1 = { name: "User", message: text1 }
        this.messages.push(msg1);

        fetch( $SCRIPT_ROOT+'/predict',{
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({ message: text1 }),
            mode: 'same-origin',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
              'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
            },
          })
          .then(r => r.json())
          .then(r => {
            let msg2 = { name: "Sam", message: r.answer };
            this.messages.push(msg2);
            this.updateChatText(chatbox)
            textField.value = ''

        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
            this.updateChatText(chatbox)
            textField.value = ''
          });
    }
```

**homepage.html**

```html
<div class="container">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="chatbox">
        <div class="chatbox__support">
            <div class="chatbox__header">
                <div class="chatbox__image--header">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/circled-user-female-skin-type-5--v1.png" alt="image">
                </div>
                <div class="chatbox__content--header">
                    <h4 class="chatbox__heading--header">Chat support</h4>
                    <p class="chatbox__description--header">Hi. My name is Sam. How can I help you?</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="chatbox__messages">
                <div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="chatbox__footer">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Write a message...">
                <button class="chatbox__send--footer send__button">Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chatbox__button">
            <button class="btn-light"><img src="./images/chatbox-icon.svg" width="45px" height="45px"/></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $SCRIPT_ROOT='{{ request.path }}'
</script>
```

Comment: ``Method Not Allowed (POST): /`` - means your function is not accepting post methos it accpets only get method.

Comment: @Ankit Tiwari so how do I allow it to accept POST knowing that I already had set my method to POST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***`Method Not Allowed (POST): /`*** - means your function is not accepting post methos it accpets only get or other safe methods.
you're not changing any state of your database so you don't have to use post request you can use get intead of post

```
class HomePageView(Notif, TemplateView):
    template_name = "homepage.html"

    @staticmethod
    def predict(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request == "POST":
            text = self.request.get_json().get("message")
            # check if text is valid
        response = get_response(text)
        message = {"answer": response}
        return JsonResponse(message)

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(HomePageView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

and change your urls like this

```
urlpatterns = [ 
    path('predict', HomePageView.predict, name="predict"),
]
```

and in your javascript change method post to get

```
fetch($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/predict', {
    method: 'GET',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        message: text1
    }),
    mode: 'same-origin',
})
```

Comment: still the same result bro...

Comment: Hello @jpf911 does your url is perfect please provide your ``$SCRIPT_ROOT`` value

Comment: okay its value is "127:0.0.1:8000" or rather '/' that's why it says Method Not Allowed (POST): /

Comment: can you provide you parrent class i see you're getting ``self`` as first arg inside your ``predict()`` methos can you provide full view with parrent class

Comment: class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "homepage.html"

Comment: okay, so for generic ***TemplateView*** you have only get method implemented. You should implement post method to allow post request.